# Calculate value (table 02) based on the formula field from table 01 (python)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, jupyter-notebook

I have a case where i need to calculate the value (column in table 02) based on the formula which is coming as a value other table (column in table 01).

**The Table 01 containing formula with other fieds is as follow.**

| Rank | position | Sign | combo | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 903 | + | Choice 01 | 903;+;901;+;899;+;900; |
| 3 | 902 | - | Choice 02 | 902;-;901;-;899; |
| 2 | 005 | + | Choice 03 | 005;+;003;+;001;+;004; |
| 2 | 006 | - | Choice 04 | 006;-;031;-;001; |
| 1 | 031 | - | Choice 05 | 031;-;030;-;029;-;027;-;028 |
| 1 | 032 | + | Choice 06 | 032;+;030;+;029;+;027;+;028;+;022;+;025; |

1. The formula with lower rank should be calculated first,like if the **Rank = 1** then this should be calculated first then followed by **Rank = 2** and so far.
2. The formula field contains the position/item_key of the **Table 02** which simply states that which **Item_key** should be added or substracted to calculate final value.

The Rank column basically identifies the hierarchy of the positions, like if the rank is 1 then this position needs to be calculated 1st so that it may be used in the calculation of other positions. For example in **Table 01** position 031 is at rank 1 so it should be calculated 1st as in position 006 (which is rank 2) uses the position 031 in the formula.

**The Table 02 containing Item_key & value is as follow.**

| Item_key | Item | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Chair | 150 |
| 003 | desk | 250 |
| 004 | table | 250 |
| 012 | room | 500 |
| 022 | mirror | 45 |
| 025 | garden | 1005 |
| 027 | lamp | 29 |
| 028 | flower pot | 25 |
| 029 | table lamp | 30 |
| 030 | glossy glass | 25 |
| 899 | table cloth | 25 |
| 900 | cahir cushion | 25 |
| 901 | rug | 25 |

**The final result should look like this.**

| Position | combo | Descriptio (optional) | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 903 | Choice 01 | rug, table cloth, chair | 75 |
| 902 | Choice 02 | rug, table cloth | 0 |

(The description column is optional)

1st row of result is compromised by the item_key 901,899 & 900. So it should add the values of that item_keys as there is addition in the formula.

2nd  row of result is compromised by the item_key 901 & 899. So it should subtract the values of that item_keys as there is subtracton in the formula.

**Edit 01: Is there anyway this could be handled with python (pandas dataframe)? Any leads how to handle this would be great. I am new to python. I tried to do this is SQL query but not successful**

Thanks in advance

Comment: The 4th line of first table has 0031 and last line has 022 which is also missing.

Comment: I am trying really hard to understand your question, but I am struggling. What is the relationship between these two tables?

Comment: I get what you are doing but your sample data needs more examples. You don't illustrate the rank, can a formula include both + and - or is it always one or the other?

Comment: @Psycho : Thanks for the comment. Sorry for the typo. I edited the question.. Hope it helps..

Comment: @Aron : Thanks for the comment. So Table 1 is basically containing all the formulas and the positions, formula tell how to calculate that pirticular position. For example position 901 can be calculated by subtracting position 899 from 901. Now the values of 899 and 901 can be taken from Table 02.. So table 01 is like a reference sheet.. Hope this helps..

Comment: @Stu: Thanks for your time.. I edited the sample data and define what rank is for, hope it helps. The formula will always have either + or - for a pirticular posision. I added a sign column as well for better understanding..

Comment: I would suggest you to process your data within a particular code, not just using query. Then it could be easier